# How to condition all cells of a notebook to a specific SeedRandom?

Tags: evaluation, random, code-request, cells

Is there a way to fix `SeedRandom[.]` for an entire notebook? If I carry out many calculations using random numbers, I need to give a separate code `SeedRandom[45]`, for example, for each cell in the notebook. This is inefficient for calculations done in many different cells because I need to indicate the same seed for each cell.

How can I set `SeedRandom[.]` once for all random number-based computations done in various cells in a notebook?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If you are using non-random data, then couldn't you just define it somewhere and reuse it?

Comment: @MarcoB: I am not using non-random data. I am only using random data. I have a notebook of many calculations in different cells based on random number generations. For all these calculations, I want to set a single `SeedRandom[.]` for the entire notebook.

Comment: The objective doesn't seem well defined. `SeedRandom` sets the initial seed, but we don't know how many "fetches" you need between re-seedings. There could be multiple calculations in one given cell that need a random value. And some other cell might not need any randomness. One possible interpretation of your objective would be that after every single random value generation, the seed is reset back to 45. But, as @MarcoB pointed out, that would eliminate the randomness, so that can't be what you're asking for. But I can't think of an alternate interpretation.

Comment: I think OP is clear what he wants - each cell should be evaluated with `SeedRandom[45]` before evaluation of the code of the cell.

Comment: try also evaluating  `$PreRead = (SeedRandom[45]; #) &;`  before other cells in the notebook.

Comment: @kglr: If I am not mistaken `$PreRead` will be applied to each line (expression) of the cell, not only once at the beginning of the cell.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, you are right.

Comment: @lericr: Suppose that I have three cells, each contains several random number generation routines. I just want to fix `SeedRandom[45]`, for example. There are two options fro me to fix the random seed. (1) I can give `SeedRandom[45]` at the beginning of each cell or (2) I should be able to fix `SeedRandom[45]` for the entire notebook without repetition of it at each cell. @azerbajdzan has correctly guessed my objective. My intention is not to repeat `SeedRandom[45]` at the beginning of each cell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellProlog :> (SeedRandom[45])]
```

Then before evaluating any cell `SeedRandom[45]` is evaluated.

```
RandomInteger[10]
RandomInteger[10]
RandomInteger[10]
RandomInteger[10]
```

---

```
9

4

9

0
```

Next cell gives the same output:

```
RandomInteger[10]
RandomInteger[10]
RandomInteger[10]
RandomInteger[10]
```

---

```
9

4

9

0
```

To cancel `CellProlog` evaluate:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellProlog :> (None)]
```